# Why is using $s in jq --argjson s "2000" different from using "2000" in the JQ code?

Tags: bash, jq

I am trying to write a bash script which parses from the nobel prize JSON file. The first argument is the year, and the second is the category.

```
set -- 2000 physics  # set $1 to 2000 and $2 to physics
jq -cr --argjson y "$1" --arg c "$2" \
  '.prizes[] | select(.category == $c)| select(.year == $y )' <<'EOF'
{"prizes": [
  {"category": "math", "year": "1999"},
  {"category": "physics", "year": "2000"}]}
EOF
```

...has no output, whereas it should output a single line with

```
{"category":"physics","year":"2000"}
```

---

However, with only the category coming from a variable, it works:

```
set -- physics  # set $1 to physics
jq -cr --arg c "$1" \
  '.prizes[] | select(.category == $c)| select(.year == "2000" )' <<'EOF'
{"prizes": [
  {"category": "math", "year": "1999"},
  {"category": "physics", "year": "2000"}]}
EOF
```

...correctly emits the line given above.

Thus, only the numeric year has trouble being passed -- whatever the problem is, it doesn't apply to the category.

Comment: When you say that `$YEAR` is "linked" to `$1` do you mean that you have `YEAR=$1` in  your script?   And why do you use `$CATEGORY` for the first example and `$category` for the second one?

Comment: I've edited a [mcve] into the question, with code someone could copy-and-paste to run to see the problem themselves without any changes or unprovided input files, and exact expected output given. Please try to do this yourself in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Evidently in the JSON file, the year is a string, so you should use `--arg y $YEAR` or `--arg y "$YEAR"`.

With the shell variable YEAR set to a value such as 2000, the effect of `--argjson y "$YEAR"` is to set the jq variable $y to an integer:

```
$ jq -n --argjson y "2000" '$y|type'
"number"
```

Comment: Thank you. I was doing the wrong way around. All I had to add was `$y|tostring`